# Application has intermittent connection errors when connecting to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, network-programming

We have an MVC4 application hosted on a VM server that uses an entityframework style connection string to connect to an instance of SQL server hosted on another VM server on the same ESX host, both are also on the same subnet IP address range i.e. 172.16.164.XX. The problem we are encountering is that if the application has not been used by users for a short while and a user then attempts to access the application, the user will fail to connect to the db to retrieve data. They will attempt a number of times and eventually the application will successfully connect to the DB and the application can be used without any issues or connection failures.

These are the typical errors returned by the application...this is what was recorded in the logs when I attempted to login today (this happened about 9 times before success):

1. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was
   successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred
   during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 -
   The specified network name is no longer available.) --->
   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified
   network name is no longer available
2. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and
   that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
   (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a
   connection to SQL Server) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
   (0x80004005): The network path was not found
3. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified network name is no longer available.) ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The specified network name is no longer available

We thought it could have something to do with our DNS server but we have added the SQL server IP address and host name to the host file on the application server. We have also added the SQL server IP address to the connection string in the web.config, but this behavior persists. Any help or suggestions appreciated -we are really struggling to find a solution to this issue

Comment: It's a little odd that it's using three different providers in your error messages: `TCP Provider`, `Named Pipes Provider` and `SSL Provider`. Have you tried limiting its options to just one, e.g.: `Server=tcp:SqlServerIpAddress,SqlServerPortNumber;`? Specifying a port number in the connection string, as opposed to an instance name, also helps to rule out another common source of problems: SQL Browser Service, which relies on udp/1434 traffic to resolve an instance name to a TCP port number that the client can then connect to.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks - we have not tried this - will get back to you on results

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I have attempted your fix and the behaviour persists, so unfortunately has not resolved our issue.